# How i can do that the div of my template are 100% width and 100% heigth?

Tags: css, vue.js

i'm trying to do that my div will are 100% but I can't do it.
My code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <Calendar/>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import Calendar from '@/components/Calendar.vue';
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue';
</script>

<style scoped>
div{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

And I got it:

[image]

Why i get all the components there?

Comment: I recommend that you use your devtools to find out why this is not taking all the place. Not a Vue issue per se.

Comment: I saw that my component app is like the width and heigth of my component calendar, why?

Comment: All my components get the same width and heigth

Comment: Why make all `divs` 100% by 100%? What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? See [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score -1):

To set a element's height to 100% of the browser window, you can simply use the `vh` property of CSS:

```
div {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
}
```

It's good to give this height to the root element of your app, so the root's height will always be equal to the browser window's height.

**Tip-**
If you see a vertical scrollbar after applying `vh` this is because of extra margin and padding of the body, so do this-

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Read more about [viewport vs percentage units](https://bitsofco.de/viewport-vs-percentage-units/)

Comment: This will bring more issues down the road.

Comment: Hey, can you give an example?

Comment: I am using vh property on my root element in vuejs/html projects and didn't find any major issues.

Comment: It was for the main.css , but now is fixed. Thanks so much to all!

Comment: Scrolling, responsive, aspect ratio, overall flow, browsers' menu bars are some that come to my mind. There are workarounds but that one is a hard definition do far.

Comment: As far as I used this, I can say, `vh` responsively calculates the size of an element based on the user’s browser’s window size. Other elements like you said menu bars, need to be adjusted accordingly as per UX requirements.

Comment: The thing is that they "jump" when you scroll up and down on mobile browsers. Not the best UI experience.